# Nuxt browser crash when open multi tabs

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

I have a vue nuxt application that work very good when I use single tabs

When I open 3 tabs, for the application.
The 2 first tabs works good and continue working
but the 3's tab does not work
This happened in chrome and in firefox (so it does not the browser)

The page loaded in the first load, but when trying to move to another page seems that page script does not loaded and the app failing. (the status of the request does not complete and stay on pending)

[image]

Answer (score 16):

In development mode Nuxt.js creates 2 persistent connections to the server to receive hot updates and to keep pages active. Each browser has their own limit for the number of concurrent connections to a specific server a site is allowed to have so if you open the same Nuxt.js site in multiple tabs of the same browser you could exceed your browser's limit.

More info: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6202#section-5.1

Comment: Wow, I cannot believe I did not know this & that it was unbelievably hard to find the answer. I was testing my activation flow where I sent emails & opened a new tab when clicking on the activate link. When I finally ended up with three tabs my components wouldn't load in and gave me a chunkloaderror / failed to load async component.
Turns out, this was the problem. Thank you.

Comment: Searching for days... This was the issue!

Comment: Perhaps it's helpful to point out that this only happens when running `yarn dev`. Running `yarn generate` or `yarn build` first, followed by `yarn start` allows multiple tabs to work as expected.

Comment: same thing with NPM. Phew, thanks guys, happy to know why now... if it doesnt happen in production then no worries!!

Answer (score 2):

from [Pimile](https://github.com/pimlie) in the GitHub [issues](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/6007) says:

"I think because Chrome has a default limit of 6 HTTP sockets per domain. Eg for me it says Waiting for an available socket when I open the 7th tab."

So try to test in on firefox, and maybe review this issue, ti could help https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/6007

Comment: In the git issue manniL mention: 
"If using Firefox you can increase this limit by navigating to about: config and setting network.http.max-persistent-connections-per-server to a higher number"

Have you tried it?